# Ubuntu "service" command

Tags: service, terminal, ubuntu-15.10

I type in the following command on two separate machines both running Ubuntu:

`service ssh status`

Output of machine 1:

`ssh start/running, process 25369`

Output of machine 2:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-03-31 15:56:49 BST; 4min 1s ago
 Main PID: 2172 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           ├─1825 sshd: (some username) [priv]
           ├─1843 sshd: (some username)@pts/0
           ├─1844 -bash
           ├─1868 su root
           ├─1869 bash
           ├─2172 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
           └─2176 systemctl status ssh.service

Mar 31 15:56:49 (computer's hostname) systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 31 15:56:49 (computer's hostname) sshd[2172]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 31 15:56:49 (computer's hostname) sshd[2172]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

I then type the following command:

```
service ssh restart
```

Output of machine 1:

```
ssh start/running, process 25369
```

No output whatsoever on machine 2.

I get similar results with all the services (not only with SSH).  How do I get machine 2 to output the same as machine 1 when dealing with the `service` command?

Comment: You don't. This is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with systemd...  So I removed it by running:

`sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`

The "service" command is finally outputting the same as any other Linux distribution...  Without the unneeded extra garbage!

Comment: You removed it by installing something?

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Open source (communism) based operating systems are messed up like that.  I googled "ubuntu remove systemd"